# Display Center inside the select list?

Tags: css

This is my first here in stackoverflow, I would like to ask if it is possible to display the select option in center? Please the see image [attach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B3pQ.png).

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="keyword[]" id="edit-keyword" size="9" class="form-select" onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }">
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="211">AI</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="176">Carbon Capture</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="186">Clean energy</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="196">COVID-19</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="216">Digital Twins</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="201">Digitization</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="181">Energy Mix</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="26">Hydrogen</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="206">IoT</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="31" selected="selected">Keyword 2</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="226">LNG</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="191">Oil ＆Gas</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="221">Power Plant</option>
    </select>
```

CSS:

```
.form-select {
    display: inline-block;
    /* display: flex; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    overflow-y: unset;
}
.form-select option {
    /* position: relative; */
    float: left;
    display: inline-flex;
    /* width: calc(100%/10); */
}
```

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Please provide some code and context. Yes, it is possible to display the select options that way however, it is unclear exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @kameron Mayer: I updated my questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what point or what position you are trying to display this. However, in order to accomplish what you posted in your image, I think this can lead you on the right path.

```css
.form-select {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   white-space: pre-line;
 }

.form-select option {
   background: white;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 5px;
  }

option:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

select {
 text-align-last: center;
 padding-right: 29px;
 direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" name="keyword[]" id="edit-keyword" size="9" class="form-select" onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }">
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="211">AI</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="176">Carbon Capture</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="186">Clean energy</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="196">COVID-19</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="216">Digital Twins</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="201">Digitization</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="181">Energy Mix</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="26">Hydrogen</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="206">IoT</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="31" selected="selected">Keyword 2</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="226">LNG</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="191">Oil ＆Gas</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="221">Power Plant</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.form-select {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}

.form-select option {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:fit-content;
    max-width:150px;
    
}

option:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" name="keyword[]" id="edit-keyword" size="9" class="form-select" onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }">
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="211">AI</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="176">Carbon Capture</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="186">Clean energy</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="196">COVID-19</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="216">Digital Twins</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="201">Digitization</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="181">Energy Mix</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="26">Hydrogen</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="206">IoT</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="31" selected="selected">Keyword 2</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="226">LNG</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="191">Oil ＆Gas</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="221">Power Plant</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel for your answer but I would like to display the list options inline and if there's an overflow it will display next line but in the middle. 
Sorry my explanation is so bad

Comment: but is possible to display it in like float center. Because right now the list value was on left aligned

Answer (score 1):

If you treat the options as text and use `text-align: center` and `white-space: pre-line` to the select and set `display:inline-block` to the `options`. The Options should be centered properly.

```css
.form-select {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre-line;
}

option {
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

option:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

select {
  text-align-last: center;
  padding-right: 29px;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" name="keyword[]" id="edit-keyword" size="9" class="form-select" onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }">
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="211">AI</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="176">Carbon Capture</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="186">Clean energy</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="196">COVID-19</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="216">Digital Twins</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="201">Digitization</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="181">Energy Mix</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="26">Hydrogen</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="206">IoT</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="31" selected="selected">Keyword 2</option>
        <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" type="submit" value="226">LNG</option>
    </select>
```